# How make android Gridview items clickable

Tags: android, gridview

I have an fragment in which gridview is populated and when I click a gridview item control will transfer to another activity through intent here the problem is when I am clicking gridview multiple times at a time it is opening the opening the activity that many times then how can I make the gridview item clickable only once

```
myGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          //  Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                         new MyAsync(getActivity(),position+1).execute();
        }
    });
```

in place of that Intent I am using Asynctask there some network operation is going and then in its postexecute method I am placing the intent

Comment: Can you post more of your code? This shouldn't be happening... Also there's no point in having the isClicked variable because you always set it to true before you check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside on click method no need to set `onItemClickListener` to `null` just use `GridView.setClickable` method  to make GridView click-able or unclick-able :

Declare ProgressDialog in Activity:

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
```

Show progress bar before starting next Activity:

```
@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     myGridView.setClickable(false);     
     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
     pDialog.setCancelable(false);
     pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
     pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
     pDialog.show();   
     new MyAsync(getActivity(),position+1).execute(); 
  }
```

and inside `onPostExecute` set GridView click-able again and dismiss ProgressDialog:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // start next activity here
            myGridView.setClickable(true); 
           if (pDialog != null)
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
       }
```

Comment: @user3530829: are you showing progress bar before starting `MyAsync` Task?

Comment: @user3530829: then show progress bar before starting task

Comment: but when we clicking faster multiple times it is again opening multiple times 
@ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: and when we are navigating back multiple times in our fragment progressbar is not getting dismissed@ ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @user3530829: use `myGridView.setEnabled(false);` instead of `myGridView.setClickable(false); `

Answer (score 0):

You can use flag to control the clickable

```
  boolean flag = false;

    myGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                  if(flag == false){
                Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                flag = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting click time and update time everytime when clicked on Gridview Item that will make gridview item click only one time.

```
  private long mLastClickTime = 0;

  myGridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                    return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps!